# How do I monitor the NRPE daemon on remote Icinga servers

Tags: icinga, nrpe

Our network has one Icinga master and 23 Icinga satellites. NRPE runs on every satellite as well as the master. Is there a Nagios plugin I can run on the master to monitor whether nrpe is running on the satellites? We need to be alerted when it's not running on the satellites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

/facepalm

check_nrpe is the answer. Needed more coffee.